# Javascript change href value based on identity of another object on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page with a Call Us button like:

```
<a class="various classes" href="tel:555-555-5555" title="call us">Call Us</a>
```

Elsewhere on the page, I have a list of product features like

```
<div class="divclass">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="t-label">Location</td>
                 <td class="t-value">CA</td>
            </tr>                                                               
            <tr>
                <td class="t-label">Mileage</td>
                <td class="t-value">170444</td>
            </tr>                                                                    
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

My goal is switch the phone number used in the a href based on the contents of one of the product features. For example if Location is CA or WA, it will be one phone number, and if the location is OH or NY, it will be another.

To achieve this I think I can use something like the following to target and change an href:

```
var a = document.getElementById('myElementID');
    a.href = "tel:777-777-7777";
```

But none of the objects in play have IDs, so I can't use getElementById to target either the a or the Location value I want to base the change on.

Even assuming I did have IDs to work with, I'm not sure the best way to make the change conditional on the contents of the Location Value.

Questions:

1. What is the best method to target ID-less DOM objects such as those above?
2. How can I make the href change contingent on the contents of the Location value? If/Else statement?

Comment: Is the CA/WA/OH/NY value always contained within the second cell of the first row?

Comment: you can use document.querySelectorAll("classname") for all the <a href> but make sure that they have a common class name that identifies them as a phone number.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually no. I will need a solution that is generalizable to the list being varying lengths and in varying orders. I think netizen's answer below has that capacity. astigmatik Yes I do think I could use that as the list appears within a div with a classname, that is unique on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
let target = document.querySelector('a[href="tel:555-555-5555"]'); // first one
let labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.t-label'));
let locationLabel = labels.find((td) => textContent === Location);
let location = locationLabel.nextElementSibling.textContent;
let numbers = {
  CA: 111-111-1111,
  NY: 222-222-2222,
};
target.href = 'tel:' + numbers[location];
```

Comment: Pseudo coding this for my understanding while developing this implementation: 1) target the phone number I want to change, 2) create array of all t-labels, 3) create object containing the t-label in the array where text content = Location, 4) create an object containing the text content that is next-sibling to Location, 5) define list of numbers, 6) change link to 'tel:' plus the info at index [location] of numbers list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information what type of back-end you are using or you are creating the row dynamically or not, but i am providing a general idea how i tackle my problem when i encountered same problem.

```
            <tbody> 
                <?php foreach($obj as $key=>$val){ ?>
                    <tr>
                       <!-- generate row in loop -->    
                       <td><?php echo "data1" ; ?> </td>
                       <td><?php echo "data2" ;  ?> </td>
                            <?php $objid = $obj[$key]['objid'];
                                  $objkey = $tableInfo[$key]['objkey'];
                             ?>  
                       <td><button id="demonstration" onclick="doSomething(event,'<?=$objid; ?>','<?=$objkey; ?>')">Example</button></td>
                    </tr>
               <?php  }?>
              <!-- loop end for table -->
            </tbody>
            
            <script>
                function doSomething(e, a, b){

                    e = e || window.event;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    let aa = a;
                    let bb = parseInt(b);
                    let baseurl =  '<?= $this->baseUrl; ?>';
                    let url = baseurl+'/home/edit/id'+"/id/"+aa+"/bb/"+bb;
                    
                    window.open(url, '_self');
                }
                
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    //this is just a general idea 
                });
            </script>
```

***Note*** - At this moment my profile is not good enough so that i can't comment in your question for fetching more info and i really want help you and , give you a general idea so that you can tackle your problem. Please forgive me if i misinterpreted your question.